# Mediawiki Releases RSS Feed?

Tags: rss, mediawiki, reminder, feed, atom-feed

Suppose I run a small wiki powered by [MediaWiki](https://mediawiki.org). I want to keep mediawiki up to date, but in order to do this I need to remember to check the Mediawiki homepage. This can get quite tedious, so I have been looking for an RSS/Atom feed that I can add to my feed reader, but I can't find a decent one.

The news page history RSS/Atom feed (found [here](https://www.mediawiki.org/w/index.php?title=News&feed=atom&action=history)) contains lots of edits related to vandalism, and so isn't ideal.

Does anyone know where I can find an RSS/Atom feed that I can add to my feed reader that will notify me of new MediaWiki releases?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the closest to what you want is [the mediawiki-announce mailing list](https://lists.wikimedia.org/mailman/listinfo/mediawiki-announce):

> Low-traffic list for announcements of new MediaWiki releases and security updates.

If you want to get an RSS feed of the emails to this mailing list, you can use [the Gmane view of the list](http://dir.gmane.org/gmane.org.wikimedia.mediawiki.announce).

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using LastRSS
Advanced RSS Ticker
Ajax invocation Dynamic Drive DHTML code library.
Visit Dynamic Drive website for this script
In the folder named LastRSS
Open the file named Bridge.php
Add your MediaWiki RSS Feed URI to the RSS Feed Reader
If you just needed the correct MediaWiki RSS Feed URI to use
For Example
https://www.MediaWiki.com/api.php?hidebots=1&hidecategorization=1&hideWikibase=1&translations=filter&urlversion=1&days=7&limit=50&action=feedrecentchanges&feedformat=rss

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer! Unfortunately, this doesn't answer this question. Here I asked if anyone had the URL of an RSS feed to subscribe to, but your answer is about displaying it somehow on a webpage.

Comment: Oh. I see the miscommunication. Should I delete my answer?

Comment: I think so, as the answer above has already been marked as accepted and your answer does not answer my question. In future, I'd suggest attempting to answer questions that don't already have an accepted answer (unless you've got a good reason to do so) :-)

Comment: Can you delete the comment. I don't have the option here on the mobile app. Thanks.

Comment: Comments need to be deleted to delete an answer?